# My Js file is not linking to my html. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my Htnl section, I have put it as shown here, in the head section as well as at the bottom. I have tried it in code pen and have no issues so it has to  be how I am linking it to my page?

Ive been stuck on this for awhile. Ive checked my JS code with no errors. I have read everything I can and I have not been able to fix this. should be as simple as attatching to the header but this has not been the case

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TechPort.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="TechPort.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<section class="headline">
        <div class="container2">
           <div class="text"></div>
        </div>
      </section>


    class TextScramble {
    constructor(el) {
      this.el = el
      this.chars = '!<>-_\\/[]{}—=+*^?#________'
      this.update = this.update.bind(this)
    }
    setText(newText) {
      const oldText = this.el.innerText
      const length = Math.max(oldText.length, newText.length)
      const promise = new Promise((resolve) => this.resolve = resolve)
      this.queue = []
      for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        const from = oldText[i] || ''
        const to = newText[i] || ''
        const start = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
        const end = start + Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
        this.queue.push({ from, to, start, end })
      }
      cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameRequest)
      this.frame = 0
      this.update()
      return promise
    }
    update() {
      let output = ''
      let complete = 0
      for (let i = 0, n = this.queue.length; i < n; i++) {
        let { from, to, start, end, char } = this.queue[i]
        if (this.frame >= end) {
          complete++
          output += to
        } else if (this.frame >= start) {
          if (!char || Math.random() < 0.28) {
            char = this.randomChar()
            this.queue[i].char = char
          }
          output += `<span class="dud">${char}</span>`
        } else {
          output += from
        }
      }
      this.el.innerHTML = output
      if (complete === this.queue.length) {
        this.resolve()
      } else {
        this.frameRequest = requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
        this.frame++
      }
    }
    randomChar() {
      return this.chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.chars.length)]
    }
  }
  

  const phrases = [
    'Hello!',
    'ImHeather',
    'IT Support & System Admin',
    'Customer Service Expert',
    'Tech Junkie',
  const el = document.querySelector('.text')
  const fx = new TextScramble(el)
  
  let counter = 0
  const next = () => {
    fx.setText(phrases[counter]).then(() => {
      setTimeout(next, 1000)
    })
    counter = (counter + 1) % phrases.length
  }
  
  next()
```

Comment: JavaScript has to go in `<script>` tags. Remove the JavaScript you added inside the body then change the script tag in your head to `<script src="TechPort.js" defer></script>`.

Comment: Have you saved your script file in the same folder as your html ? You need to provide the script tag the relative path to it (that is if your error is showing up on your local machine)

Comment: Its not in the body.  Just the way it is here. the script is an external file

Comment: Yes they are in the same folder. and also relative path is set ..

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is the request for the JavaScript file made?  Is the URL of that request what you expect?  What is the server's response?

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TechPort.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="TechPort.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<section class="headline">
        <div class="container2">
           <div class="text"></div>
        </div>
      </section>

<script>
    class TextScramble {
    constructor(el) {
      this.el = el
      this.chars = '!<>-_\\/[]{}—=+*^?#________'
      this.update = this.update.bind(this)
    }
    setText(newText) {
      const oldText = this.el.innerText
      const length = Math.max(oldText.length, newText.length)
      const promise = new Promise((resolve) => this.resolve = resolve)
      this.queue = []
      for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        const from = oldText[i] || ''
        const to = newText[i] || ''
        const start = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
        const end = start + Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
        this.queue.push({ from, to, start, end })
      }
      cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameRequest)
      this.frame = 0
      this.update()
      return promise
    }
    update() {
      let output = ''
      let complete = 0
      for (let i = 0, n = this.queue.length; i < n; i++) {
        let { from, to, start, end, char } = this.queue[i]
        if (this.frame >= end) {
          complete++
          output += to
        } else if (this.frame >= start) {
          if (!char || Math.random() < 0.28) {
            char = this.randomChar()
            this.queue[i].char = char
          }
          output += `<span class="dud">${char}</span>`
        } else {
          output += from
        }
      }
      this.el.innerHTML = output
      if (complete === this.queue.length) {
        this.resolve()
      } else {
        this.frameRequest = requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
        this.frame++
      }
    }
    randomChar() {
      return this.chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.chars.length)]
    }
  }
  

  const phrases = [
    'Hello!',
    'ImHeather',
    'IT Support & System Admin',
    'Customer Service Expert',
    'Tech Junkie',
  const el = document.querySelector('.text')
  const fx = new TextScramble(el)
  
  let counter = 0
  const next = () => {
    fx.setText(phrases[counter]).then(() => {
      setTimeout(next, 1000)
    })
    counter = (counter + 1) % phrases.length
  }
  
  next()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```